# Why does stripping metadata decrease the duration of my MP3 file by 0.03 seconds?

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, mp3

I have a file, input.mp3, which, running ffprobe on it gives the following:

```
[mp3 @ 0x559431400a00] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from '../backup/1.mp3':
  Metadata:
    album           : DW01-The Colour Of Magic
    artist          : Terry Pratchett
    album_artist    : Terry Pratchett
    comment         : Read By Nigel Planer
    composer        : Nigel Planer
    genre           : Discworld
    publisher       : Polygram
    title           : Colour Of Magic 1 of 6
    track           : 1
    date            : 1983
    id3v2_priv.WM/Provider: A\x00M\x00G\x00\x00\x00
    id3v2_priv.WM/WMCollectionGroupID: \xe4\xbba\xf0\xf2\xcd.D\xab\x92b\xeb{\x8b\x9a\xce
    id3v2_priv.WM/WMCollectionID: \xe4\xbba\xf0\xf2\xcd.D\xab\x92b\xeb{\x8b\x9a\xce
    id3v2_priv.WM/UniqueFileIdentifier: A\x00M\x00G\x00a\x00_\x00i\x00d\x00=\x00R\x00 \x00 \x00 \x002\x007\x007\x008\x004\x003\x00;\x00A\x00M\x00G\x00p\x00_\x00i\x00d\x00=\x00P\x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x00 \x003\x003\x007\x00;\x00A\x00M\x00G\x00t\x00_\x00i\x00d\x00=\x00T\x00 \x00 \x001\x005\x00
    id3v2_priv.WM/WMContentID: h\x86H@^\xe6qF\x95T\x04m\x01P\x90\x7f
    id3v2_priv.WM/MediaClassSecondaryID: \x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00
    id3v2_priv.WM/MediaClassPrimaryID: \xbc}`\xd1#\xe3\xe2K\x86\xa1H\xa4*(D\x1e
    id3v2_priv.ZuneCollectionID: \x1d\xcb\xdf\xf3X89D\x81\xd1\xd0s#P\x00\xf8
  Duration: 01:08:19.30, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 274x417, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (attached pic)
    Metadata:
      comment         : Cover (front)
```

There are various things I want to do with this file, like concatenating it with other files, and then splitting it into small segments. But for now, I will just consider the simple case of removing the metadata, since that by itself produces problems similar to what I am running into with those other operations. When I run the following command on the above file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -map 0:a -c:a copy -map_metadata -1 output.mp3
```

Then I run ffprobe on output.mp3

```
Input #0, mp3, from 'output.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 01:08:19.27, start: 0.011995, bitrate: 32 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 32 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavf
```

Why does the duration decrease by 0.03 seconds? And why is the start time no longer 0? Also, why, when I open this file up in an vlc, does it seems to have trouble figuring out the duration? With the original file, it knew the duration instantly. But with the new file, it seems to be trying to estimate it, slowly getting closer over time as I play it.

Codec information in vlc (and it is identical for both files)

```
Stream 0
    Codec: MPEG Audio layer 1/2 (mpga)
    Type: Audio
    Channels: Stereo
    Sample rate: 44100 Hz
    Bits per sample: 32
    Bitrate: 32 kb/s
```

Comment: In VLC can you go to Tools -> Codec Information and paste the information shown there?

Comment: @Mokubai: Working on that (can't actually copy/paste from that screen, so I need to type it manually)

Comment: The first line of the output of ffprobe states this, “Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate…” Knowing it is an estimation, that explains that.

Comment: @Giacomo1968: Except that is only present for the original file. The one which vlc has no trouble figuring out the exact time. Also a related question would be, why this difference between the first and second file?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

MP3 files don't have the same kind of internal structure that e.g. an MP4 or MKV file would – a "plain" MP3 is just a raw series of audio frames and doesn't have its duration stored anywhere. For constant bitrate MP3 files the duration can be calculated from the file's length, while for VBR it can only be determined by evaluating the whole file frame-by-frame.

That is, **unless** the encoder stored the duration & VBR information in a "[LAME INFO tag](http://gabriel.mp3-tech.org/mp3infotag.html)" (aka "Xing VBR tag"). Practically all encoders and players support this tag now, and most MP3 files have it.

From the ffprobe output it looks like your original file *doesn't* have such a tag, while the new file does ("encoder: Lavf" is part of it, added by FFmpeg). So I would expect the opposite result – the duration should be known for the new file, but not for the original – that is, unless FFmpeg added inaccurate information.

---

In fact, a plain MP3 file doesn't even reserve any space for metadata – Xing and ID3 tags are actually disguised as special audio frames that most decoders know to ignore – which also means that the estimated duration of an MP3 file may depend on how much metadata it contains or used to contain. A simple estimation such as "size÷bitrate" will be wrong if the file has a hole remaining from ID3v2 tag removal.

You can use [Mp3Diags](https://mp3diags.sourceforge.net/) to take a look at the structure of the file. (It can also be used to fix inaccurate Xing tags that make players think the track is longer or shorter than it actually is.)

Comment: Do you know what the 'start' field is, and why that would change to some non-zero value when removing metadata?

Comment: There's no "start" field; audio data starts at 0:00:00 at byte 0 of the file. But as mentioned, both the ID3v2 and Xing tags are _disguised as audio frames,_ and it seems ffmpeg's own timestamps do not account for that. My guess is that the "audio" data between 0:00:00.0 and 0:00:00.011995 is actually the (new) Xing tag that ffmpeg itself added. (You should be able to see it in `hexdump -C out.mp3`.)

Answer (score 3):

An mp3 file contains three things: Audio blocks, metadata, and rubbish. An audio player has likely code to read and display the metadata, and it *must* have code to play the audio blocks. Rubbish is ignored.

Now the *displayed* length of the audio data has changed. There are two possible reasons:

1. The metadata editor has managed to destroy the header of an audio block (and audio blocks are about 30ms usually). With the header destroyed, the audio block is now rubbish, so this has actually reduced the audio length.
2. The audio player doesn’t scan all audio blocks and adds up their duration, but guesses the number of audio blocks based on file size. And maybe it doesn’t take metadata into account, so having more metadata makes it overestimate the audio length. Since you deleted metadata, the estimated audio length was reduced. The real length is unchanged, and likely less than is displayed.

Comment: Little-known fact: for certain songs, the file contains 100% rubbish! (Just kidding.)